# How can I remove blank strings from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I scraped a really bad formatted string from a website and converted it to an array. Now tt contains some **empty strings or only-whitespace-strings** which I want to remove but it doesn't work. 
**I tried already apply_filter($array)** without success. Also I tried to iterate and filter out this elements manually, but it doesn't work at all. It seems like I can't access this elements:

```
foreach($array as $elem){
     if($elem == " " || $elem == "")
          echo "Want access this: " . elem . "<br>";
          //No Output
}
```

How can I access this array-elements and remove? Here is the array (the nodes i wanna remove are the string(21) elements (so length 21?!):

```
array(47) { [0]=> string(31) "16.11.2016" [1]=> string(23) " " [2]=> string(21) "" [3]=> string(21) "" [4]=> string(21) "" [5]=> string(21) "" [6]=> string(21) "" [7]=> string(21) "" [8]=> string(31) "18.01.2017" [9]=> string(148) "
"Some text inside this one

" [10]=> string(21) ""}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for the hints, but nothing did the trick because the problem is that the length of whitespace-Strings is different. According to a previous answer I'm trying now to catch this elements with **preg_match("/\s{2,}/", $val);** but I can't catch them. In the online tester 
 (http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kNL) it works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: please change the data. this is sensitive!

Comment: i'm sorry. I was in java-mode

Comment: @PhilippSander no worries :)

Comment: @PhilippSander this is not `java` this is `php` :)

Comment: `" "` is not an empty string. And `string(23) " "` is weird. There should be `23` characters in `" "` but there is only one. The same for `string(42) "21.06.2017       "` a.s.o.

Comment: @axiac nothing weird about that, there _are_ 23 white space characters in that string. But because the result of this debug output is _interpreted as HTML_ by the browser, it is condensed to a single space character, because that is how HTML handles whitespace. Outputting a `<pre>` before this debug output, or checking the actual source code in the browser helps.

Comment: Please read the comment of @CBroe above and post the actual output of the PHP script, not whatever wants the browser to show you in the page after it interprets it as HTML and "fixes" it.

Comment: @CBroe your explanation has a point. However, in the original content of the question (the OP edited it in the meantime), the `string(42) "21.06.2017 "` contained more than one whitespace after `2017`.

Comment: I wrote /^\s*$/ so that it matches strings whether thay are empty or contain one or more spaces. You state that you're after empty strings, but form what I see you only look for strings containing 2 or mroe spaces. It seems that what you said you wanted to do and what you actually want to achieve are different things. You should consider editing your question so explain what you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested, use `array_filter()` and `trim()` to filter out elements which are empty strings or contain whitespace only:

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function ($element) {
    return is_string($element) && '' !== trim($element);
});
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score -1):

you can use array filter

```
function odd($var)
{
    return(trim($var) != "");
}


$array = array(1, " ", 2, " ");
print_r(array_filter($array, "odd"));
```

regards.

Comment: always leave an explanation - no one learns from copying and pasting :p

Comment: it is in the documentation http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php#refsect1-function.array-filter-examples

Comment: do you really think people will google it though after copying and pasting? Always add a reference link and just explain - easy way to get upvotes :)

Comment: No worries :) :D

Answer (score -1):

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($v,$k) {
    return $v !== "";
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

See http://php.net/array_filter

Comment: And this solution with array_filter ?

Answer (score -1):

First :
`if($elem == " " || $elem == " ")`

To me, it seems you wrote two times the same comparison.

Regarding your array cleansing, maybe you will get what you seek for by trying this :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if (preg_match('/^\s*$/', $val) OR $val === NULL) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

$array = array_values($array);

That code removes entries from the array if they are `NULL`, contain nothing or only space characters and the like.
Since your array is indexed, I added the last line which builds the array once again with new, consecutive indexes, so that there are no holes among them where entries have been removed.

Hope it helps.